# Rails delayed job referring to old release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, capistrano3, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a project running on Rails 4.2 and using delayed_job (4.0.6) for my background jobs. I've had an issue now for a couple of weeks where the video encoding fails when it looks for the file to process. The error message contains an old release path that has already been removed a while ago by Capistrano (3.4.0).

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/www/apps/<app>/releases/20150906031337/static/post_assets/videos/000/436/600/original.mov
```

Capistrano will remove old releases automatically which is fine (I keep 5 releases), but I am restarting delayed_job on every deployment. I have the pids in a shared folder and they match up with ones I get when I run `ps -ef | grep delayed_job` after deployment.

I run 2 workers (`set :delayed_job_workers, 2`) and I'm using 'capistrano3-delayed-job' (1.4.0) for the deployment formulas.

I do have a lot of jobs in the queue when restarting, but it's not consistent with a video encoding job running at that time that could be interfering or something (I do keep 5 releases after all, so even if the job is running on the second last one, the folder should still exist). There are a lot of smaller jobs though which might be running at the time of deployment, but DJ should be able to handle that and restart gracefully anyway right?

It seems that workers are still lingering somehow, or am I missing something else?

Comment: Restart workers on every deployment is causing problems ?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, yea maybe it's a matter on HOW they are restarted but I need to restart them since they must pick up the latest code changes, right?

Answer (score 0):

On restarting delayed job workers on every deployment and poiting to latest release must be solving this.

There's a gem for this

[capistrano3-delayed-job](https://github.com/platanus/capistrano3-delayed-job)

If you don't want to use gem follow for complete info.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Delayed-Job-tasks-for-Capistrano-3#if-you-dont-want-to-use-a-gem

Also refer if needed https://github.com/imnithin/capistrano3

If these tasks are not supported due to version mismatch, execute custom command from cap3.

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')
      execute "cd '#{release_path}' && RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(rails_env)} script/delayed_job -n 2 restart"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do already use this gem like I wrote though. I would assume the gem should take care of it better than custom code. Another thought I had was the new restart method of the new passenger. I haven't read up on it but might try to downgrade.